# Group with levenshtein distance

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I have postgreSQL 9.2

My task is to find similar names in table (limited by some levenshtain distance).

For example, the distance is 3, the table has data:

```
|           name            |
|***************************|
|       Marcus Miller       |
|       Marcos Miller       |
|       Macus Miler         |
|       David Bowie         |
|       Dave Grohl          |
|       Dav Grol            |
|           ...             |
```

The result I want to get is like this:

```
|       Marcus Miller, Marcos Miller, Macus Miler       |
|       Dave Grohl, Dav Grol                            |
|           ...                                         |
```

Or

```
|       Marcus Miller, Marcos Miller                    | 
|       Marcus Miller, Macus Miler                      |
|       Dave Grohl, Dav Grol                            |
|           ...                                         |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b ON b.id < a.id AND levenshtein(b.name, a.name) < 3;
```

But it is too slow with my datum.

Comment: The `Group By` idea is a non-starter - what would be the output of `Select _levenshtein_group_func_('Marcus Miller', 3)` be? Put another way: you could have 3 names *a*, *b* and *c* such that the Levenshtein distance from *a* to *b* was 3, and the distance from *b* to *c* was 3; so the groups would be *(a,b)*, *(b,a,c)*, and *(c,b)* - SQL Group By cannot put the same entry into more than one group, so could never produce that result.

Comment: Incidentally, your mock query is incorrect, as well - the `HAVING` clause should be `HAVING count(*) > 1`, as `COUNT(grouped_column)` is always 1 by definition.

Comment: Why `HAVING COUNT(grouped_column)` is always 1? For example, query `SELECT name FROM users GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1;` returns  names of users, which name is not unique.

Comment: Hm, you're right, it will, because `COUNT(name)` counts the number of non-null values of `name` in the group, even though they are all identical (as opposed to `COUNT(DISTINCT name)`, which *would* always be 1). `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` would be the same unless there are `NULL` values in `name`, and a lot more obvious to the reader. `COUNT(some_function(name))` is particularly unintuitive, as the function is generally irrelevant.

Comment: You cannot do that with levenstein, look at @lpsmith 's answer of the reason why. But you if you want to group by all names, which *sounds similar*, you can use `soundex()` or the `metaphone()` functions (which are in the same module) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a significant conceptual error with your question;   `GROUP BY` takes certain [equivalence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (in the mathematical sense) as an argument and uses that to [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) a SQL relation into [equivalence classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

The problem is that the relation you describe,  namely,  "are two strings within a certain edit distance of each other",   is not an equivalence relation.   It's symmetric and reflexive,  but not transitive.     To illustrate,  what should the answer be if I added a series of names to your dataset that morphed "Marcus Miller" into "Dave Grohl",  with each name in the series being within that edit distance from the previous?

However, there are algorithms to partition a data set using things that aren't equivalence relations,  such as geometrical distance.   [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is one of the best known examples.   Perhaps there is a way to adapt k-means or something similar to this problem,  I don't know.